# Filter Observable<any[]> with Observable<string>

Tags: angular, observable, angular7

Using Angular 7 I have a search input which is connected to an `Observable<string>`

```
searchValue = new FormControl("");
this.searchChanges$ = searchValue.valueChanges
```

I have another `Observable<Record[]>` which I get from firebase, i'm trying to filter the array with the string I get from the search input using:

```
return this.searchChanges$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(recordsObserver, (searchValue, records) => {
    return records.filter(record => record.title.includes(searchValue));
  })
);
```

The problem is that the list isn't updated until something is changed in the input, what is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When both observables are meant to work as a primary source for your new observable, you should rather use **combineLatest** over **withLatestFrom**.
This way, when one of your source observables triggers, your new combined observable will trigger as well.

Another handy tool when it comes to such use-cases is the utilization of **startWith**